# In which TextBox is the cursor.?

Tags: javascript, textbox, dom-events

I have 4 textboxes and a submit button in my web page.
Suppose the user enters data in 2 fields and then clicks the submit button.
I now want to know in which textbox the cursor was located just before the submit button was clicked.

Any idea on how to do this in Javascript?

Comment: document.activeElement
try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question *does* specifically say **in javascript**, but FWIW here is another option in jQuery:

[Working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mtU9U/1/)

HTML:

```
<input id="in1" type="text" /><br />
<input id="in2" type="text" /><br />
<input id="in3" type="text" /><br />
<input id="in4" type="text" /><br />
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Submit" />
```

jQuery:

```
var inFocus = false;

$('input, textarea').focus(function() {
  inFocus = $(this).attr('id');
});

$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    alert('Cursor was last in element id: ' + inFocus);
});
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted.brilliant...!!
Thanks..!!

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `document.activeElement`, which returns the currently focused element.

Comment: I entered data in the 3rd textbox and clicked the SUBMIT button.
Now `document.activeElement` is returning **BODY** .
But i want the **NAME** of that 3rd textbox.

how to do this.?

Comment: @Narendra: If you want to know which element was _most recently_ active, handle the `blur` event for all of the elements and record the most recent one in a variable.

Comment: @Narendra *The activeElement attribute on Document objects must return the element in the document that is focused. If no element in the Document is focused, this must return the body element.* [Source: HTML Living Standard - Updated 30 August 2013](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#focus-management)

Answer (score 2):

you can use document.activeElement

here is the simple example for the same.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetActive () {
            if (document.activeElement) {
                var output = document.getElementById ("output");
                output.innerHTML = document.activeElement.tagName;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onclick="GetActive ();">
    Click anywhere on the page to get the active element
    <input id="myInput" value="input field" />
    <button>Sample button</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
```