# Get id of active textfield

Tags: javascript, html, forms

If I have 4 text boxes in my form, at any point can I get id of text field  in which user is filling the information at the moment.

Eg. in following context, I should be able to get id of textbox 3.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you store the last textbox (textarea?) selected?

Comment: have u tried `document.activeElement `??

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: I was doing a minor mistake and hence wasn't getting the output. 
@adiga it's ok if you do not wish to answer.
Stackoverflow is a community for developers to ask question. Why to demotivate them? Not everyone is at same level of expertise. There are times when you don't know what to exact term you should search for, and asking here helps. People here are not bots, they understand problems in layman terms.

Comment: @AmanSehgal Adiga is correct actually. Broad questions are discouraged unless they demonstrate an attempt. This particular question is relatively straightforward, but in general you should try to demonstrate your research and effort in the question.

Comment: I am not demotivating.I'm only asking you to make sufficient research before posting a question which you have not done. If you're still stuck then you can post a [MCVE]. Include all the things you've tried for context. I'm not sure why you said "*exact term you should search for*", because I just googled the title "Get id of active textfield javascript" and got this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538004/in-which-textbox-is-the-cursor

Answer (score 2):

You can get the currently active element using `document.activeElement`, so its ID using `document.activeElement.id`.

Focus on any of the textboxes in the snippet to see how it works:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  console.log("Active element: " + document.activeElement.id);
},1000);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="1">
<br>
<input type="text" name="" id="2">
<br>
<input type="text" name="" id="3">
<br>
<input type="text" name="" id="4">
```

Comment: Thank you it works. I was doing a minor mistake because of which I wasn't able to run this same solution.

Apologies for not providing my snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getAttribute()` like the following way:

```js
function myFunc(thatText){
  console.log(thatText.getAttribute('id'));
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="txt1" onchange="myFunc(this)" placeholder="1"/><br/>
  <input type="text" id="txt2" onchange="myFunc(this)" placeholder="2"/><br/>
  <input type="text" id="txt3" onchange="myFunc(this)" placeholder="3"/><br/>
  <input type="text" id="txt4" onchange="myFunc(this)" placeholder="4"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: I have a dropdown to click and then i add text to input or textfield which ever is in focus but via this its showing dropdown as active for id i want the id of textfield or input

Answer (score 0):

There can be an onkeyup function. pass `this` from the DOM and in js use that argument to get id

```js
function getElem(elem) {
  console.log(elem.id)

}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="test" id="1" onkeyup="getElem(this)">
<br>
<input type="text" name="test" id="2" onkeyup="getElem(this)">
<br>
<input type="text" name="test" id="3" onkeyup="getElem(this)">
<br>
<input type="text" name="test" id="4" onkeyup="getElem(this)">
```